# Почему мы должны расширять класс только через прототип?

Tags: javascript, прототипное-наследование

Заметил такой пример:

```js
Number.prototype.times = function(f, context) {
  let n = this.valueOf();
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) f.call(context, i);
};
```

Почему мы должны лезть в прототип класса `Number`, а не расширять прямо сам класс?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если мы будем добавлять метод `times` напрямую в функции-конструкторе `this.func_name = function(){...}`, то у каждого объекта этого класса будет собственный метод `times`. Так вот, чтобы поберечь оперативную память и не создавать в каждом экземпляре новую функцию, мы определяем её на прототипе и теперь, так как прототип существует в единственном экземпляре, наша функция тоже будет в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: @YokoFranci Рад помочь).

Comment: Что за ересь? Если мы добавим метод прямо в конструктор, то у экземпляров его не будет вообще

Comment: @AlexeyTen наверное имелось в виду, что если в функции конструкторе каждый раз создавать новую функцию... Например `function a(){ this.f = function(){}}`. Но написано криво, да.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, я ошибся. У экземпляров будет функция, если мы добавим её в функции - конструкторе `this.func_name = function(){...}`, а если добавить функцию вот так: `Number.func_name = function(){...}`, то получится статическая функция. Уже исправил ответ